# postgresql: slow after backup and restore (even with analyze)

Tags: database, performance, postgresql

From time to time a backup my database like this:

```
pg_dump mydb > /path/to/mydb.db
```

Then I will perform some operations on it on a different server. These operations mostly add data to the database, so that the database will be (sometimes a lot) bigger after that.

After these operations, I restore the database on my original server like this:

```
dropdb mydb
createdb mydb
psql mydb < /path/to/mydb.db
```

After I have done that, the database speed is for some reason slower than before. For some queries it is about a factor of 20. This also doesn't really change if I run an ANALYZE after my restore. This all would somehow makes sense, since the size of the database has increased.

But here comes the weird part: If I uninstall postgresql completely, create the database and restore then my new (bigger) database, it will be fast again.

What can be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: `vacuum analyze`. Plus:tune the regular suspects.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: Do these queries run slow many times? You may see better performance after the cache is warmed up. Also, are you restoring to the exact same hardware/folder/db or another machine or pg instance?

Comment: @JoeLove Yes, they always run slowly. If it had something to do with the cache, then wouldn't it be weird, that it runs fast, after a complete reinstall?

Comment: Do you see differences in the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE before and after the change? And can you see if you're IO- or CPU- bound?

Comment: @FrankHeikens I did not use EXPLAIN before. But yes, there were some differences between before and after ANALYZE. CPU activity doesn't seem to be super high, so I would say that I am more IO bound.

Comment: Do you know if there is any difference on the old server/database and the new one? And if you're IO bound, did you check other processes on your machine?

Comment: @FrankHeikens yes, that's maybe an important bit I forgot to mention. When I restore the database it will have been changed. So I dump it, move it to another server, perform some operations, move it back and restore it. The new version usually contains quite a lot more data in some tables than the old one.

Comment: Ok, that's a different story: It looks like the "old" database fits in memory (cache) and the "new" one doesn't. Check EXPLAIN ANALYZE on the "new" (but slow) queries and start optimizing. You might need different configuration settings, indexes or queries. But when the new database has much more data than the old one, different behavior is expected. But it can still be fast!

Comment: @FrankHeikens Yeah but the weird thing is still that I can uninstall postgresql completely, wipe out everything, then install it again and restore my new (bigger) database and it will be fast again. (I also just updated my question, making it hopefully a bit clearer, what the problem is)

Comment: Could be a rogue process, bad statistics, or whatever, but it's hard to help you without seeing the whole picture. But it's the first time I've heard about something like this in my 10 years of experience with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Once again, Just to verify: Is this all on one machine? (same hardware, same exact pg config, same libraries, etc?)

Comment: @JoeLove Yes, it is one the same machine, with the same configuration.